# React Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Key is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react app and I get this error:

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Can someone explain what is the reason for this error?

This is my code:

```
import { Avatar } from "@mui/material"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { collection, doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore"
import { db } from "../../FireBase/Firebase"
import "./ViewClass.css"

const ViewClass = ({ viewData }) => {
  const [announcement, setAnnouncement] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewData && viewData.id) {
      const viewRef = collection(doc(db, "Announcements", "Classes"), viewData.id);
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(viewRef, (snap) => {
        setAnnouncement(snap.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
      });
      return () => unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [viewData])

  return (
    <div>
      {announcement.map((item) => (
        <div className="View" key={item.id}>
          <div className="View_Cnt">
            <div className="View_Top">
              <Avatar />
              <div>{item.sender}</div>
            </div>
            <p className="View_Test">{item.text}</p>
            <img className="View_Img" src={item.imageUrl} alt={item.text} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ViewClass;
```

I see that the key is undefined, why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: are you sure you have an id for each item? {item.id}

Comment: yes each item has a different id in the id of the main Class

Comment: I recommend using the React Dev Tools plugin to inspect your component. You can view the value of `announcement` and dig down into each item to determine which one has an `id` of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you have an id for each item? {item.id}

You can possibly use the traversal operator ? like this:

```
{announcement?.map((item) => (
    <div className="View" key={item?.id}>
```

Or as @Code-Apprentice mentioned *Somewhere you are setting key to undefined*

The other option could be using the index if you know what you're doing:

```
{announcement?.map((item, index) => (
    <div className="View" key={`item-${index}`}>
```

Comment: `item?.id` will still have the same problem. If `item` is `undefined` then `key` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yup agree. In the case the issue could be that some of the items may have undefined as the value

Comment: presumably the array won't have any `undefined` elements. If this is the correct assumption, I would prefer to have `item.id` instead of `item?.id`. I think the OP is trying to determine why `id` is undefined for one or more elements in the array.